# How to change the volume in System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer()

Tags: c#, volume, windows-media-player

I write the code below but I cannot change the volume of the sound. I changed "a.Volume = 5;"  but this did not affect anything. How can I change the volume of the audio. Thanks

```
var a = new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();

a.Open(new System.Uri(@"\a.wav”))

a.Volume = 5;

a.Play();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Volume](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer.volume.aspx) properties accept a [Double](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx) value between 0 (no sound) and 1 (maximum volume)